# Can't save Altair chart as SVG from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-lab, altair

When trying to export an Altair chart in SVG format from a Jupyter Notebook running inside Visual Studio Code, I am prompted "You'll need a new app to open this data link", but no apps are listed for handling "data" links (inc in the Microsoft Store).

No issues exporting a chart in PNG format, or exporting in SVG format when running in a browser window. Not sure whom to blame: Altair, Vega, Jupyter, or Microsoft...

[image: Microsoft Store prompt]

Comment: If PNG works but SVG is blocked, then the fault lies with VSCode. You'll have to figure out how to configure VSCode to allow download of SVG files from within Jupyter.

Comment: Strangely enough, when I run Jupyter Lab in a browser, I get a data URL for the PNG file, and a blob URL for the SVG file...

Answer (score 2):

- A acknowledged bug in vscode-jupyter is causing Failure to save altair chart as SVG .

[Github issue : Unable to save SVG of altair chart in vs-code Jupyter .](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5827)

- Alternative workaround until bug is  fixed

Altair can do this via the altair_saver package, which can be installed with:

```
conda install altair_saver
```

or

```
pip install altair_saver
```

**Additional Requirements for altair_saver package : one of two backends. {Selenium / Nodejs }**

[Detailed Instructions for installation of  Additional  Requirements](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver#readme)

To save an Altair chart object as a  SVG image, you can use

```
alt.renderers.enable('altair_saver', fmts=['vega-lite', 'png'])   
Chart.save("chart.svg")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the GitHub issue!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this bug was fixed in the latest version of the Jupyter VSCode extension!